# How to unload kernel module 'nvidia-drm'?

Tags: debian, kernel, systemd, nvidia, kernel-modules

I'm trying to install the most up-to-date NVIDIA driver in Debian Stretch. I've downloaded `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.48.run` from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/132530/en-us), but when I try to do

```
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.48.run
```

as suggested, an error message appears.

```
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-drm' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or 
         the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs    
         that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading,   
         and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to     
         reboot your computer.
```

When I try to find out who is using `nvidia-drm` (or `nvidia_drm`), I see nothing.

```
~$ sudo lsof | grep nvidia-drm
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
~$ sudo lsof -e /run/user/1000/gvfs | grep nvidia-drm
~$
```

And when I try to remove it, it says it's being used.

```
~$ sudo modprobe -r nvidia-drm
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia_drm is in use.
~$
```

I have rebooted and started in text-only mode (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 before giving username/password), but I got the same error.

Besides it, how do I "know that my kernel supports module unloading"?

I'm getting a few warnings on boot up related to nvidia, no idea if they're related, though:

```
Apr 30 00:46:15 debian-9 kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Apr 30 00:46:15 debian-9 kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Apr 30 00:46:15 debian-9 kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Apr 30 00:46:15 debian-9 kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.82  Wed Jul 19 21:16:49 PDT 2017 (using threaded interrupts)
```

Comment: can you try to do it in rescue mode?

Comment: See this [issue on github](https://github.com/Witko/nvidia-xrun/issues/32) : `systemctl stop systemd-logind` before unloading the modules.

Comment: @vfbsilva My rescue mode is strange, it's looping forever, identifying all USB devices again and again. I managed to press Enter, give the root password and get a prompt, but there's no /dev, so no mount of the disk is possible.

Comment: @GAD3R All I have is `systemctl stop systemd-logind.service`, but this closes the screen and takes me back to the graphic login, where I have to do Ctrl+Alt+F2 again.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I imagine you want to stop the display manager which is what I'd suspect would be using the Nvidia drivers.

After change to a text console (pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and logging in as root, use the following command to disable the graphical target, which is what keeps the display manager running:

```
# systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

At this point, I'd expect you'd be able to unload the Nvidia drivers using `modprobe -r` (or `rmmod` directly):

```
# modprobe -r nvidia-drm
```

Once you've managed to replace/upgrade it and you're ready to start the graphical environment again, you can use this command:

```
# systemctl start graphical.target
```

Comment: I managed to uninstall it (using your answer), and install the new version to the point where there was no more working graphic mode. I had to format the PC and reinstall Debian. Now to a completely different set of bugs... All this just to see "GPU" as an option of rendering in Blender, and I still don't see it. Proprietary drivers sucks!

Comment: This worked for me without the `modprobe` step.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't need `modprobe` step neither.

Comment: I can't remove nvidia-drm even when in the text console. Any idea how I can forcebly remove it?

Comment: @addison Note that it's not enough to just *be* on a text console, you need to stop X11 or Wayland or whatever is using the nvidia driver from the kernel. The point of the `systemctl isolate` command is to do that. But it's possible that's not correctly configured in your system... Check `ps -ef` and see if you can spot what might be using the driver, then have that process stopped. That should allow you to unload the driver.

Comment: Works but # modprobe -r nvidia-drm  not necessary.

Comment: Thanks you, thaa helped

Answer (score 19):

### CUDA Installation

1) Download the latest [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=runfilelocal)

**2) Switch to tty3 by pressing Ctl+Alt+F3**

**3) Unload nvidia-drm before proceeding.**

3a) Isolate multi-user.target

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

3b) Note that nvidia-drm is currently in use.

```
lsmod | grep nvidia.drm
```

3c) Unload nvidia-drm

```
sudo modprobe -r nvidia-drm
```

4d) Note that nvidia-drm is not in use anymore.

```
lsmod | grep nvidia.drm
```

5) Go to your download folder and run the cuda installation.

```
sudo sh cuda_10.1.168_418.67_linux.run
```

6) Answer any prompts during installation.

7) When installation has finished, confirm that the CUDA Version has been updated.

```
nvidia-smi
```

8) Start the GUI again.

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
```

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r nvidia-drm` raises error `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia_drm is in use.`

Comment: This is gold. Wanted to upvote this. But it appears I already did a couple of years ago. This answer saved my day twice. :)

Comment: Great answer. N.B. you may run into the same error, but repeated with 'nvidia-modeset' once `nvidia-drm` has been unloaded. It's worth to check the status of any persistence daemon running, and disabling it if yes using:
`systemctl status nvidia-persistenced`
`systemctl disable nvidia-persistenced`
`systemctrl stop nvidia-persistenced`

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem by disabling the GUI, rebooting, logging in and installing the driver, enabling GUI, and reboot.

Please make sure you know your username and password!!!

Open a terminal and write

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
sudo reboot 0
```

Now login and you'll get to a terminal directly, install the driver Do note that I am installing here the 440.44 **so you need to modify for your driver version**.

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.44.run
```

After installing the driver enable the GUI and Reboot:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
sudo reboot 0
```

You should be done

In my case, nvidia-smi reported the new version 440.44, whine in the Ubuntu 18.04 Software & Updates Utilities, Additional Drivers Tab shows 435!! Another NVIDIA mystery, but heck my new docker works!!!

Comment: Disabling the GUI as above is the only thing that worked for me through ssh!

Comment: Same for me, I was unable to unload nvidia-drm manually ("module not found" or something, although it was loaded) but disabling the GUI and rebooting did it.

Comment: Great answer! I was struggling with solution provided by the top answer for several hours  (`systemctl isolate multi-user.target` only gives me black screen). Your answer saved my day!

Answer (score 6):

`lsof` lists any files that are in use by userspace processes. But `nvidia_drm` is a kernel module, so `lsof` won't necessarily see whether or not it is actually in use. (The module file won't be open because the kernel has already completely loaded it into RAM. But the module might be providing services to the userspace or other kernel components, and *that* is what prevents the unloading of the module.)

Run `lsmod | grep nvidia.drm` and see the numbers to the right of the `nvidia_drm` module name. The first number is simply the size of the module; the second is the use count. In order to successfully remove the module, the use count must be 0 first.

If the X11 server is running and using the `nvidia` driver, then the `nvidia_drm` kernel module will most assuredly be in use. So you'll need, at the very least, switch into text console and shutdown the X11 server. Usually this can be done by stopping whichever X Display Manager service you're using (depends on which desktop environment you're using).

As the error message said, if you are running `nvidia-persistenced`, you'll need to stop that too before you can unload the `nvidia_drm` module.

Comment: After Ctrl+Alt+F2, `lsmod` is telling me there's 1 process using `nvidia_drm`. So I did `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop`, which went `ok` in stopping it. But still 1 process in `lsmod`. Now inside Gnome, `ps aux | grep nvidia` shows `[irq/129-nvidia]` and `[nvidia]` but no `nvidia-persistenced`. Also, here `lsmod` shows 2 processes using `nvidia_drm`. I'm stuck.

Comment: The nvidia modeset module was also preventing me from installing nvidia-440 using the .run installer from nv's website. There were no clues about how to unload this module, but this answer also helped me, because nvidia-persistenced was running and holding the module in-use. `systemctl stop nvidia-persistenced` works, then `modprobe -r nvidia_modeset`. Now, the installer doesn't complain about nvidia-modeset.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem.

> *Reason: nvidia.drm package was in use

I fixed it by purging all NVIDIA packages.

Remove all previous NVIDIA installations with these 2 commands:

`$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

 `$ sudo apt-get autoremove`

Module should be removed.

Reboot and go forth.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me.  I think it might have been because I instlled the cuda toolkit 11.8 before attempting to update the driver.  Once all that stuff removed, was able to install driver.

Answer (score 3):

You report in comments that stopping the systemd-logind service takes you back to the *graphic* login.  If you have a graphical login then X is running, so the video driver is loaded and in use.  This very likely explains in part why the nvidia-drm module is in use.

Additionally, you betray an apparent misconception when you say

> I have rebooted and started in text-only mode (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2
>   before giving username/password), but I got the same error.

Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 switches to a virtual terminal #2, which may well be configured for text-mode login, but that's a far cry from "starting in text mode".  If you had a graphical login screen on the default virtual terminal then X is running, and switching to a different VT doesn't change that.  You're just logging in to a non-X session.

The first and easiest thing to try is to actually shut down the X server.  The old-school way to do this would be to log in to your text-mode session and execute the command

```
telinit 3
```

to switch to runlevel 3.  That should work with systemd, too, but the native systemd way would be to instead run

```
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

Both of those require privilege, of course, so you'll need to use `sudo` or make yourself root.

If that doesn't remove the module, or at least make it possible for you to do so manually, then your next best bet would be to boot the system directly into runlevel 3 (multi-user target), or maybe even into runlevel 1 (rescue target).  I usually do this by adding "3" (or "1") to the end of the kernel argument list at boot time via the bootloader.  You can also change the default boot target as described in [this article](http://landoflinux.com/linux_runlevels_systemd.html).

Do also note that the nVidia driver is available in pre-built packages for most Linux distros.  Few include those packages in their own standard repos because the driver is, after all, proprietary, but you can surely find a reputable 3rd-party repo that has it.  I strongly recommend using such packages instead of running the installer directly, but to get there from where you are now, you may need to first manually uninstall the driver.

Comment: I managed to uninstall it (using Filipe's answer), and install the new version to the point where there was no more working graphic mode. I had to format the PC and reinstall Debian. Now to a completely different set of bugs... All this just to see "GPU" as an option of rendering in Blender, and I still don't see it. Proprietary drivers sucks!

Comment: @Rodrigo, I'm sorry you had such a poor experience.  But that sort of problem is an example of why I recommend using packages instead of performing manual installations.

Comment: Yes, I prefer using packages. But I've read somewhere that GPU option in Blender wasn't enabled probably because of an outdated driver...

Answer (score 1):

Stopping `systemd-logind` fixed it for me:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-logind
```

This is suggested as a workaround in [this github issue](https://github.com/Witko/nvidia-xrun/issues/32#issuecomment-332097279) on the nvidia-xrun github page:

> Good news guys, systemd-logind is the culprit here. The current
>   workaround is to run the following command after logging out from the
>   "nvidia-xrun" session sudo systemctl stop systemd-logind
>
> Then, you'll have manually remove the other nvidia modules and switch
>   off the DGPU manually. Here's the code snippet that runs after you log
>   out from the "nvidia-xrun" session.
>
> ```
> echo 'Unloading nvidia_drm module' 
> execute "sudo rmmod nvidia_drm"
>
> echo 'Unloading nvidia_modeset module' 
> execute "sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset"
>
> echo 'Unloading nvidia module' 
> execute "sudo rmmod nvidia"
>
> echo 'Turning off nvidia GPU' 
> execute "sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF"
>
> echo -n 'Current state of nvidia GPU: ' 
> execute "cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch"
> ```
>
> [Systemd issue on Github](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6908)
>
> [Reference link from Nvidia Linux Developers portal](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024407/linux/nvidia_drm-remains-in-use-for-no-apparent-reason-after-xorg-shutdown-/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Debian Stretch when trying to install the Nvidia drivers. When in text mod my only solution was to remove the driver, reinstall gdm and gnome-shell. I know it's a clumsy solution, but I remember I first tried fixing the gnome-shell and only removing Nvidia driver and reinstalling GDM. Turned out it was much easier to just reinstall the whole shell.

Comment: Guess I'll wait for a less clumsy solution, if any shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. The reason for the error was that I accidentally selected "Install nvidia driver" during the installation of cuda.

So, during the installation of CUDA, when you encounter the following options:

> Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 384.81? 
>   (y)es/(n)o/(q)uit:

Please select **q** , the problem will be solved.

Comment: So, what are you saying?  That the only solution is to reinstall?  That obviously isn’t the only solution; other answers have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to change system to start in text more

```
systemctl set-default runlevel3.target
```

then restart and install nvidia cuda driver
once finished you may want to change system to start in graphics mode again

```
systemctl set-default runlevel5.target
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by filbranden got me in the right direction, but did not quite work for me (it seems that at least the `nouveau` driver was always loaded and causing problems).

What did work for me, however (as shown [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/how-to-boot-to-console-text-mode-in.html) in more detail), was to temporary boot to console mode (text mode). This seemed to make sure that no `nvidia` or `nouveau` driver was loaded.

I then followed [@filbrandens answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441811/377345) for stopping/removing `nvidia-drm` and then I installed the `nvidia` driver from there and rebooted the system. The latter may have been not necessary but since it worked I listed it here.

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer for the one who are facing this problem.

For me, I have to switch the driver to be not Nvidia on software&update, then, reboot and perform  installation again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error during boot:

```
[54.285826] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

during run of the NVIDIA Builder/Installer/Configurator

It told me to use the software Updater App (additional Drivers). But this did not work because there was not other options to change the Driver

If you are a new install you could get errors with:
gcc, make, pkg-config, & libglvnd

If you are installing a new driver downloaded manually
e.g. before running this with sh...

```
$ sudo sh {NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.60.02.run}
```

1st as per other answers...

```
$ systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

ensure gcc, make, pkg-config, & libglvnd-dev are install
$ sudo apt install gcc
$ sudo apt install make
$ sudo apt install gcpkg-configc
$ sudo apt install libglvnd-dev

also

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

and
`$ sudo apt autoremove` (if you like)

Now run the builder:

```
$ sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.60.02.run
```

should get no errors during the run of the driver builder/installer/configurator

turn graphics back on???

```
$ systemctl start graphical.target
```

possibly do a reboot to check on boot everything is now ok.

Pic of my previous state:
NVIDIA 470 needed updating to 510
[image]

Final Outcome:
Wish it was cleaner:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this here just as a drastic last resort, you should avoid doing it like this if possible, first try other answers.

You can brutally kill all processes using the nvidia device and then unload the kernel modules with:

```bash
sudo kill -SIGKILL $(lsof /dev/nvidia0 |
    /bin/grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "(^\S+)( )\K([0-9]+)" |
    tr '\n' ' ')
sudo rmmod --force nvidia_drm
sudo rmmod --force nvidia_modeset
sudo rmmod --force nvidia
```